# How to control access to AWS API Gateway Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have several API Gateway "methods" (endpoints) that I want to make available ONLY to users that have specific IAM roles (policies). I have tried just about everything I can think of to do this.

Basically... all I want is to find a way to pass an access token into API Gateway (via a header) and figure out what role that access token belongs to, then let API Gateway do the work of authorizing based on the Policy attached to that role. Am I way off base?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the **Authorization** to `AWS_IAM` in **Method Request** > **Authorization Settings** and pass the `Authorization` HTTP request header when calling your API methods.

The `Authorization` header requires that you calculate the digital signature for your signed request.

**Signing your requests**

This [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/signing-requests/) will walk you through the steps required to calculate the digital signature for your signed requests.

If you just want to test your API using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), this can be done by choosing the **Authorization** tab and selecting **AWS Signature** for the authorization **Type**. Enter your AWS IAM user's access key ID in the **AccessKey** input field and your IAM user secret key in **SecretKey**, specify an appropriate **AWS Region** that matches the region specified in the invocation URL. Enter `execute-api` in **Service Name**.

This should construct a header similar to the following:

```
POST /prod/yourapi HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/json
X-Amz-Date: 20170302T080546Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=YOURACCESSKEY/20170302/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping for more of something like this: I create a user in some 3rd-party (or custom) db or whatever... the user logs in using his credentials... then I create a session in some sort of db and keep a list of the IAM roles that to which that user belongs... then when the user hits the endpoint... AWS figures out to which roles that user belongs and does the authorization at that point.

Comment: I think you'll need to implement an [API Gateway Custom Authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) in your case, without the need to store the IAM roles in your DB. The access level for each user would be evaluated according to the authorization token linked to each user (via user groups in your app, for example) that will be passed to your custom authorizer.

Comment: Cognito user pools is exactly what you are looking for. API Gateway has had support for cognito user pools since the launch of the feature http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html.